# A simple $n$-regular graph with no cycles of length $>3$ has at least $2n$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $H$ be a simple graph that has no cycles of length more than $3$. Each vertex has degree of $n$. Is it possible to prove $H$ has at least $2n$ vertices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary node $x$. Now, consider the set of $k$ neighbors of $x$, denoted by $N(x)$. Now, let's consider another arbitrary node $y \in N(x)$. Clearly, if $z \in N(y)$, then $z \not \in N(x)$, because otherwise $x, y, z$ would form a 3-cycle. Thus $N(x)$ is disjoint with $N(y)$. Since both $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ consists of $k$ elements, we have $2k$ nodes at minimum.

Comment: The "no-3-cycle" property of your graph stands out as the strongest property. So I work from there, and figured out that in order for it to have no such subgraph, then adjacent pairs of nodes cannot have nodes in common. After figuring this out the rest comes naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $u\in V(G)$. We know that $N[u]=k+1$ since $G$ is $k$-regular. None of $u$'s neighbors are adjacent since $G$ is triangle-free. So all the vertices in $N(u)$ are adjacent to $k-1$ vertices in $G-N[u]$ and $|G-N[u]|\geq k-1$. Thus $|G|=|N[u]|+|G-N[u]|\geq (k+1)+(k-1)=2k$.